# Slept 6 hrs vs slept for 6 hours

Tags: grammaticality

> I woke up at 8 today, that means I **slept for only** 6 hours last night.

Vs

> I woke up at 8 today, that means I **slept  only** 6 hours last night.

Sleep vs sleep for? Which one is correct? I often hear people saying "I slept x hours." Is this correct? Or is For necessary?

Comment: Please see [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169729/chance-for-me-to#comment340179_169729)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both seem to be used in more or less the same meaning. "For" is not necessary but may be used. Google results suggest that "for" is rather more common.

> The participants that slept six hours each night were cognitively impaired.
>
> Those who slept for six hours kept mental abilities at a high level until about the tenth day of the experiment.